# Correct preposition in "unfit for/to this post"

Tags: prepositions, usage

- You are unfit **for** this post.
- You are unfit **to** this post.

Which sentence is correct? It would be helpful if someone explained where to use **"for"** and where to use **"to"**.

Answer (score 0):

It should be either,

"You are unfit for this post."

or

"You are unfit to serve this post."

You'll have to look up the definitions of "for" and "to" because they have so many meanings and you will just have to learn when to use them; they're difficult.  I know that "for" is used when there's a purpose involved in an activity:

"I have no money and you say you will pay my bill?  You would do that **for me**?"

means something vastly different from,

"I trusted you and you betrayed me.  I can't believe you would do that **to me**."

Comment: … to serve *in* this post.

Answer (score 0):

**you are fit or unfit to do something.**

**You are fit or unfit for something**.

> **You are eligible/ fit to apply for the post**.
>
> **You are fit or eligible for the post.**

Here is a link which helps you.

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fit_1

Answer (score 0):

Unfit **to** do something / Unfit **for** something

For example:

> This dressing is unfit *to* work.
> This dressing is unfit *for* working.